# In an Airflow DAG, how to update a params with a set of params pased via postman?

Tags: airflow-2.x

I have a master dag that executes a certain number of times a sub dag. I want the number of times the dag is executed to be determined by a parameter passed in a JSON file from the Postman. How can it update that value with the variable's value passed from Postman?

This is an example of code. I need to update the local_conf with the parameters received from Postam, and then I need to use the new step value to update the local step value:

In the example, steps equals 13, and I need to update to 20 or something similar.

I also tried to use the the output from the function "update_globals" but I get the following exceptions: airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: conf parameter should be JSON Serializable

Details:
airflow: 2.4.2
Paylaod to trigger the process:
{
"dag_run_id": "example_triger_several_time_a_sub_dag_001",
"conf": {
"steps": 20,
}
}

```
# main_dag.py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.trigger_dagrun import TriggerDagRunOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago



''' Define the parameters to pass to each sub dag''' 
global_conf = {}
local_conf = {
        "steps": 13 
        }


''' Set default args '''
default_args = {
    'owner': 'rtm-pa-consumerization',
    'start_date': datetime(2021, 6, 25)
}


def update_globals(**context):
    global x
    x = context
    return x

with DAG(
    dag_id='Example_trigger_sub_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=None
) as dag:
    
    ''' Declare check-points '''
    start = DummyOperator(task_id='Start')
    cp_setup_params = DummyOperator(task_id='CHKP_Setup_Params')
    end = DummyOperator(task_id='End')
    
    ''' Setup parameters '''
    setup_params = PythonOperator(
        task_id='Setup_Params',
        dag=dag,
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=update_globals
)

    ''' Trigger sub dag '''
    for i in range(int(local_conf["steps"])):
        local_conf["process_id"] = i+1
        data_sub_dag = TriggerDagRunOperator(
            task_id=f'Data_sub_dag_Q{i+1}',
            trigger_dag_id='Sub_dag',
            conf=global_conf,
            reset_dag_run=True,
            wait_for_completion=True
        )
        cp_setup_params >> data_sub_dag >> end
    

        
    ''' priority order '''
    start >> setup_params >> cp_setup_params
    cp_setup_params >> [data_sub_dag] >> end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DAG level params dict to supply runtime params to the DAG.
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/params.html#dag-level-params

And in Postman you can run this with
POST http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dags/runtime_param_dag/dagRuns
use the payload: { "conf": {"steps": 10}}

```html
import json
from datetime import datetime
import time
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow.models.param import Param
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

local_conf = {
    "steps":5
}

def call_sub_dag_func(**context) -> None:
    print(context["params"]["steps"])
    for i in range (context["params"]["steps"]):
        print('call sub dag')


with DAG(
    dag_id='runtime_param_dag',
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2024,1,26),
    params=local_conf,
    is_paused_upon_creation=False,
    catchup=False
) as dag:

    call_sub_dag = PythonOperator(task_id='call_sub_dag',
        python_callable=call_sub_dag_func,
        dag=dag
    )
```