airflow scheduled with dag config parameters
I am running an airflow dag, and trying to run it on a schedule. When the dag is triggered by the scheduler, the dag run_config evaluates to None.
I tried this, but it did not work for me - Airflow how to set default values for dag_run.conf
My code looks something like
def parse_conf(**kwargs):
  print(f"dag run config is {dag_run.conf}") # prints None if dag is run on scheduler

with DAG(
...
schedule_interval="* * * * *",
params={
        "test_param":"test",
},) as dag

  config_task = PythonOperator(task_id="parse_config", python_callable=parse_conf)
  ...
  start_task.set_downstream(config_task)

If the dag is triggered manually, the config is as desired.
In the config file, dag_run_conf_overrides_params is set to True

can you try with the approach in the below answer using context["params"]["test_param"] in your Python callable parse_conf function.
answer link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78017253/in-an-airflow-dag-how-to-update-a-params-with-a-set-of-params-pased-via-postman/78017614#78017614

You can use python configparser lib in dag codes:
Here's example codes:
import os
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
import configparser

schedule_time = configparser.ConfigParser()
schedule_time.read('dags/settings.ini')
AutoSet = schedule_time.get('Run Scheduler', 'Timeset')

default_args = {
    'owner': 'Dyan',
    'start_date': dt.datetime(2023, 8, 29, tzinfo=local_tz),
    'retry_delay': dt.timedelta(minutes=5),
    'catch_up': False,
    'provide_context': True
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='api_call_scheduler',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Api call Dag',
    schedule_interval=AutoSet,
    params={
        "start_date": dt.datetime.strftime(dt.datetime.today().replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc).astimezone(local_tz) - dt.timedelta(1),'%Y-%m-%d'),
        "end_date": dt.datetime.strftime(dt.datetime.today().replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc).astimezone(local_tz) - dt.timedelta(1),'%Y-%m-%d'),
        "cmd": "ALL"
    }   
)

